# RESTful DELETE with reason

Tags: rest, api-design

For a resource that will be deleted, ultimately with a soft delete (isDeleted flag), I am looking to provide a reason to store along with the resource for audit purposes.

The options I have encountered don't feel correct.

1. Custom HTTP Header
2. DELETE with Body

I have also considered instead using a PUT, but the content I would be putting is different from what makes up the resource on a typical update.

Which method makes the most sense from a RESTful perspective ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) with a body is wrong, in that it doesn't respect the semantics of the uniform interface defined in the HTTP specification.

> A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

Note that the spelling used here is the same as that of a payload for a [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) request.

Semantically, DELETE is the right choice; soft vs hard delete is "beyond the scope of the specification", which is to say it is an implementation choice.

But communicating the "reason" gives you two problems to solve.  One is where to put that reason, and the answer is, of course, to [use a header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.1).

> New header fields can be defined such that, when they are understood by a recipient, they might override or enhance the interpretation of previously defined header fields, define preconditions on request evaluation, or refine the meaning of responses.

You can look through the [message-headers registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml) to see if there is a close match to your requirements, but failing that you would define one of your own.

The second problem is figuring out how to communicate with the client so that it knows to use the header field.  The most common approach today is to just write the header into the description of the API, but that's not *quite* REST.

The REST answer is that your hypermedia specification describes how the server might communicate to the client which headers are important, and what data should be put there.  Imagine an HTML form with a "field-value" input control, and you've got the right idea.

Not many API bother to do it that way.

PUT is an intriguing choice; there's nothing in the rules that says that a resource can have only one content type, or that an endpoint must accept only one content type.

For instance, [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) defines application/problem+json, a simple representation for reporting issues from the server.  But there's no reason that you couldn't PUT an application/problem+json representation to a resource to induce a soft delete.

This specification gives you both a `title` and a `details` element to play with, so the client has room to work.

Of course, it doesn't have to be application/problem+json -- you can specify a more suitable media type of your own design.

Again, you have similar problems to the using delete with a custom header: how does the *client* discover that your resources support put deletes?

Comment: This explanation makes me feel much more comfortable with the header approach, while PUT may still be valid.  Thanks!

Comment: I went through message headers registry and it seems there isn't any that would match well. I decided to use a custom header, so the ultimate response to this question is to use DELETE with custom header.